# Is there a way to use RegEx in ASP/VBScript?

Tags: regex, asp-classic, vbscript

I have an ASP website which I need to add a RegEx match to.  Is there any support for RegEx in ASP/VBScript?

Thank you,

Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as of VBScript 5  http://authors.aspalliance.com/brettb/VBScriptRegularExpressions.asp

http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html